# Centering (verticaly) a row of text in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, scroll, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox that sometimes contains a large amount of text requiring scrolling to see all of it. Once the text is loaded/entered and a button is clicked the application steps through the text, a character at a time, making changes.

I am trying to scroll the contents of the RichTextBox to keep the row on which the change is currently taking place in the middle of the box.

I can move the caret to the top, and to the bottom, which moves the text down and puts the caret at the top of the box or moves it up and puts the caret at the bottom of the box respectively.

I can place the caret at a given character but depending on where that character is on in the visible section (within the text box) of text is the caret could be , near the top or near the bottom of the box, How do I move the whole of the text so that the line the caret is on, is scrolled to the vertical middle of the box?

Hope all that makes sense.

Comment: Have you tried simply setting the SelectionStart() property to the correct location, then calling ScrollToCaret()?  Make sure the RichTextBox has focus though.

Comment: Actually I was just coming back to say I had just tried using that too. However with a text file containing 15,356 characters, this method only guarantees the caret is in the visible section of the text. As before, it could be on the top line or the bottom line, or anywhere in between. I am looking to adjust the scroll with my code so that once it scrolls to the caret I want that line of text to be in the vertical center of the box.

Answer (score 0):

To simulate "making change" I'm just moving through one character at a time, highlighting the text in gray.

You will have to change the value of "const int offset" based on your UI (i.e., the size of your richtextbox).  Set it to the number of characters to the vertical mid-point of the control, that is, ((the number of lines in RichTextBox) / 2) * (number of characters per line).  I used a 5 line textbox with about 50 characters per line, so I set it to 100.

**Dont forget to accept answer if it helps you. Thank you**

```
    private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        richTextBox1.SelectAll();
        richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;
        richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
    }

    private void btnHighlight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const int offset = 100;

        for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.TextLength; i++)
        {
            richTextBox1.Select(i, 1);
            richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.LightGray;

            if (i - offset > 0)
                richTextBox1.Select(i - offset, 1);
            else
                richTextBox1.Select(0, 1);

            richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();

            Application.DoEvents();

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);

        }

    }
```